# how dependencies are injected in struts2 action with spring?

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I have one legacy web application based on *struts2* (primarily using annotation). While debugging i find that all the dependencies (like service layer and dao layer) 
are injected automatically in struts 2 action. I was expecting there must be some spring interceptor defined in `struts.xml` which must be doing this.

But i did not find any spring related interceptor over there. Also in `web.xml` i did not find any related stuff which must be doing this kind of work.
I am  not sure how dependencies (with *spring*) are injected in *struts2* action...

I can see `struts2-convention-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar` file in class path. Does it mean `filterDispatcher` looks for this jar at run time and if it finds it, inject the dependencies in action. Does any Interceptor also help during this process?

Comment: Can we see examples of config, and examples of the objects that have dependencies injected into them?

Comment: So you say there is no spring listener defined in your web.xml ?

Comment: @fmucar i see ContextLoaderListener in web.xml which read the xam file given against the paramter contextConfigLocation parame in web.xml. But this will instantiate only singleton beans not prototype or request scope. RIGHT? To inject the prototype beans in action, it must be done thru either interceptor or plugin?

Comment: Do you have struts2-spring-plugin as your dependency? It is one way of integrating struts2+spring. Your app may be using some custom solution. Listener manages all spring beans but still it need to intercept actions at some point to be able to inject dependencies.  Show us some configuration

Comment: @MSach:Can you look for `struts2-spring-plugin` as this plugin is responsible for giving control to Spring DI

Comment: yes umesh i can see struts2-spring-plugin in my dependencies. Does it mean filterDispatcher looks for this jar at run time and if it finds it, inject the dependencies in action.Right?Does any Interceptor also help during this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to `struts-plugin.xml` of `struts2-spring-plugin-x.x.x.x.jar`, you can find the config about *object factory and autowiring interceptor* . It uses the plugin feature of *struts2*, and you may search 'plugin' from Struts Guide for details.

Comment: Shen is correct. The ObjectFactory is responsible for creating all actions, interceptors, results, and type converters used by Struts2. By default, Struts2 uses reflection to create those objects, but there are plugins for Spring and Guice to allow those frameworks to create the objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the Dependency Injection is done with spring, check out the [spring plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/spring-plugin.html).

If not, struts2 has its own [Dependency Injection Implementation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/dependency-injection.html)
Take a look at the [Core Developers Guide](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/core-developers-guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

There must be an interceptor ..which is getting executed before action class and is doing this dependency injection using Java reflection API..or Struts 2 Reflection tool..http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/struts2-plugins/struts2-convention-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/convention/ReflectionTools.html
Check the interceptor stack.

Comment: rajesh i can seee struts2-convention-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar file in class path. Does it mean filterDispatcher looks for this jar at run time and if it finds it, inject the dependencies in action.Right?Does any Interceptor also help during this process?